# Where is __copy_tofrom_user defined? (Linux 2.6.33 PowerPC arc)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, powerpc

I am trying to study the `__copy_to_user()` and `__copy_from_user()` inline functions mentioned on [Page 65 of LDD3](http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#ReadAndWrite).

I can see that the [`__copy_to_user()` function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/include/asm/uaccess.h?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc#L435) calls the [`__copy_to_user_inatomic` function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/include/asm/uaccess.h?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc#L402) and this function calls the `__copy_tofrom_user()` function.  The fact that I have not provided a link for that last one should clue you into my issue.

I can see that `__copy_tofrom_user()` has a prototype [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/include/asm/uaccess.h?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc#L327), but I cannot find where the function is actually defined.  A [search on the Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc;i=__copy_tofrom_user) shows that it is used several places in the PowerPC architecture.  But where is the actual definition?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760278/where-is-copy-to-user-defined) but it looks like the asm-generic version does not have the `__copy_tofrom_user()` function.

**Edit:**

Here are links to the assembly for `__copy_tofrom_user()`: Looks like there is a [32-bit version](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/lib/copy_32.S?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc#L306) and a [64-bit version](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/lib/copyuser_64.S?v=2.6.33;a=powerpc#L13) implementation in this version of Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is implemented in the `copyuser_*.S` files in [the same directory](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/powerpc/lib).

(Assembler files are not indexed.)

Comment: I didn't realize that the assembler files were not indexed!